# why my bibliography is not working?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Here is the description of the book I am citing which I added in a different file named mybibliography.bib :

```
@book {MR2814476,
    AUTHOR = {Arkowitz, Martin},
     TITLE = {Introduction to homotopy theory},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer, New York},
      YEAR = {2011},
     PAGES = {xiv+344},
      ISBN = {978-1-4419-7328-3},
   MRCLASS = {55-02 (55Pxx)},
  MRNUMBER = {2814476},
MRREVIEWER = {Samuel B. Smith},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4419-7329-0},
       URL = {https://doi-org.libproxy.library.wmich.edu/10.1007/978-1-4419-7329-0},
}
```

Here is my document from the beginning:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\newcommand{\circledell}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{$ \ell $}{$\mathlarger{\bigcirc}$}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  

\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
```

And here is the part of my code in which I am citing the book:

```
\textbf{Definition $3.1.3$}\\

If $(X', \varphi ')$ and $(X, \varphi )$ are co-H-spaces and $h: X' \rightarrow X$ is a map, we say that $h:(X', \varphi ') \rightarrow (X, \varphi )$ is a $\emph{co-H-map}$ if $\varphi h = (h \vee h) \varphi'$. You can also look at definition $\, 2.2.8$ in $~\cite{MR2814476}$ to see this definition using a commutative diagram.
```

But I do not know why I did not get any references page showing my bibliography, can any tell me what is wrong in my code?

Also, what bibliography style am I allowed to do?

Comment: Why are you putting `$\, 2.2.8$` and `$~\cite{MR...}$` in mathmode? Those are textmode objects.

Comment: If you are using biblatex, did you `\printbibliography`?

Comment: What do you mean by ` \printbibliography ` ? I am writing my code in the question and I did not use this @WillieWong

Comment: You need to tell biblatex where to print the bibliography. (If you are writing a long document, it is up to you whether the bibliography comes before/after indices and appendices and so on).  I understand that the biblatex documentation is really long, but at least look at simple guides like https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Getting_started_with_BibLaTeX ; For your final question, there is a complete list of standard biblatex styles in section 3.3 of the documentation (a copy of which at https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en )

Comment: @WillieWong I corrected what you said in the first comment and still my code is not working .... I changed them into  `2.2.8` and `~\cite{MR...}` ...... yet still my code is not working

Comment: Can you clarify to me please how to use `\printbibliography`? where should I put it? does it take argument? if so, what argument it takes? @WillieWong

Comment: A few comments above I included a link to a guide published on Overleaf.com. That includes both a written summary as well as a video tutorial. Please look at them.

Comment: @WillieWong I started watching the video ... thank you!

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 and some of the links mentioned there (https://github.com/PaulStanley/biblatex-tutorial/releases is a great resource!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `biblatex` and `biber` to create the bibliography, you need to furnish a `\printbibliography` statement to tell LaTeX *where* in the document the formatted bibliography should show up.

I would also recommend loading the `xurl` package, to allow line breaks in URL-like strings at arbitrary locations.

Somewhat curiously, while your preamble features the instruction

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
```

you don't make use of it in the body the document.

A separate subject: You asked, "what bibliography style am I allowed to [use]?" Biblatex features lots and lots of style. Which ones you are either allowed to use or are required to use is something we know nothing about. I suggest you ask your publisher for advice on this issue.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%% Aside: I've stripped the preamble down to the bare minimum 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybibliography.bib}
@book {MR2814476,
    AUTHOR = {Arkowitz, Martin},
     TITLE = {Introduction to Homotopy Theory},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer, New York},
      YEAR = {2011},
     PAGES = {xiv+344},
      ISBN = {978-1-4419-7328-3},
   MRCLASS = {55-02 (55Pxx)},
  MRNUMBER = {2814476},
MRREVIEWER = {Samuel B. Smith},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4419-7329-0},
       URL = {https://doi-org.libproxy.library.wmich.edu/10.1007/978-1-4419-7329-0},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in URL-like strings

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}  % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{definition}{2}

\begin{definition}
If $(X', \varphi ')$ and $(X, \varphi )$ are co-H-spaces and $h\colon X' \rightarrow X$ 
is a map, we say that $h\colon(X', \varphi ') \rightarrow (X, \varphi )$ is a $\emph{co-H-map}$ 
if $\varphi h = (h \vee h) \varphi'$. 
You can also look at definition 2.2.8 in~\cite{MR2814476} to see 
this definition using a commutative diagram.
\end{definition}

\printbibliography % tell LaTeX to print the formatted bibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the details of the book I am citing as a part of the code? I am putting this in a separate file and I am naming it `mybibliography.bib`.

Comment: I want to message you privately about something in your answer, is there anyway to do this on this site?

Comment: @Happy - The `filecontents` environment lets users create external files -- here: `mybibliography.bib` -- "on the fly". You may email me at "loretan.mico@gmail.com". I do have a dayjob, though, so I can't predict how quickly I can respond to emails.

Comment: ok, thank you !

Comment: what does this part of your code do `\theoremstyle{definition}`? it gives me error in my code.

Comment: @Happy — The macro `\theoremstyle` is defined in the `amsthm` package. Does your code load the `amsthm` package? If it doesn’t, it’s pretty much guaranteed to cause an error.